# On closed abelian reductive subgroups of Real reductive groups

Tags: reductive-groups, algebraic-groups, lie-groups, ag.algebraic-geometry

Hello everybody. I would first like to apologise for the basic question; I'm not expert on Lie Theory. Can someone please help me with the following questions

Let $\mathrm{G}=\mathrm{K} \exp(\mathfrak{p})$ be a Real reductive group ([as in Knapp's Lie Groups: Beyond an Introduction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZHlA.png)) and let $\mathfrak{a}$ be
a maximal Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}=\operatorname{Lie}(\mathrm{G})$ such that $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$. Since ${[\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{p}]} \subset \mathfrak{k}$
($\mathfrak{k}=\operatorname{Lie}(\mathrm{K})$), the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{a}$ is commutative. Let $A:=\exp(\mathfrak{a})$ denote the corresponding
commutative Lie subgroup of $\mathrm{G}$.

My questions are:

1. Is $\mathrm{A}$ a closed subgroup of $\mathrm{G}$?
2. Is $\mathrm{A}$ a reductive subgroup of $\mathrm{G}$?
3. In otherwise, Can someone give some examples to show that 1. and 2. are not always true?

Any answer or comment will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Answers are: 1. yes, 2. yes.
A is a maximal split torus (or rather the connected component of its real points).